# How to convert a pytorch geometric graph to Networkx Multigraph?

Tags: data-mining, pytorch, graphs

I have a weighted graph stored in Data object, and I want to convert this graph to Networkx MultiGraph. Here is what I have tried:

```
data = Data(x=x, edge_index=edge_index)
print(edge_index).
```

.

> torch.Size([3, 237])

conversion

first trial

```
from torch_geometric.utils import to_networkx, from_networkx
G=to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
```

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

second trial

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
edges = data.edge_index.numpy()
edge_list = []
for i in range(data.num_edges):
    edge_list.append(tuple(edges[:, i]))
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
data.G = G
adj=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
print('here the adj is', adj.shape)
```

> Result=(18, 18) expected (23,23)

What else can I do? Thank you very much for your Input

Answer (score 1):

Check out the provided utility method [`torch_geometric.to_networkx`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html?highlight=networkx#torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx) (link to docs).

I am not sure how this would handle multigraphs.

There's also a `from_networkx`.